# How to join tables so even rows with no matches are included?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

I'm trying to join persons to shirts table in the result displaying all persons and shirts that are in color blue.

Here's my persons:

```
ID  NAME
1   Antonio Paz
2   Lilliana Angelovska
3   Michael SpringRoll
4   Poor dude
```

And shirts:

```
ID  STYLE   COLOR   OWNER
1   polo    blue    1
2   dress   white   1
3   tshirt  blue    1
4   dress   orange  2
5   polo    red     2
6   dress   blue    2
7   tshirt  white   2
8   dress   orange  3
9   polo    red     3
10  dress   red     3
11  tshirt  white   3
```

I'm doing left outer join which includes all persons and all shirts:

```
SELECT p.name,s.style,s.color FROM person p LEFT OUTER JOIN shirt s
   ON s.owner = p.id

NAME                    STYLE   COLOR
Antonio Paz             polo    blue
Antonio Paz             dress   white
Antonio Paz             t-shirt blue
Lilliana Angelovska     dress   orange
Lilliana Angelovska     polo    red
Lilliana Angelovska     dress   blue
Lilliana Angelovska     t-shirt white
Michael SpringRoll      dress   orange
Michael SpringRoll      polo    red
Michael SpringRoll      dress   red
Michael SpringRoll      t-shirt white
Poor dude               (null)  (null)
```

How can I limit the query so that only blue shirts are displayed BUT ALSO include people with empty rows so that the result looks like this:

```
NAME                    STYLE   COLOR
Antonio Paz             polo    blue
Antonio Paz             t-shirt blue
Lilliana Angelovska     dress   blue
Michael SpringRoll      (null)  (null)
Poor dude               (null)  (null)
```

You can run my example here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f440/1/0

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a LEFT JOIN not an INNER JOIN

Include s.color = 'blue' inside  the ON, not after the WHERE

ie

```
SELECT p.name,s.style FROM person p LEFT JOIN shirt s
   ON s.owner = p.id AND s.color = 'blue';
```

Comment: I don't see any downvotes, so I guess all is well ;)

Comment: No need to run it - I missed the "left" in "left join" - I thought that it was an inner join. Anyways, all is well now. We can delete all the comments, Cheers!